# avconv output_volume option - trying to understand the man page

Tags: shell, command, manpage, avconv

I'm trying to **increase** the volume of my input .wav file by means of the `output_volume` option within the `avconv` command. I would like to increase the volume by 6 dBs similarly as demonstrated in the [man page](https://libav.org/avconv.html#Examples-2).

I have my command in a script format

```
for i in *.wav; do avconv -i "$i" output_volume=volume=6dB:precision=fixed "$i{%.*}".mp3;done
```

But I receive the following error. I see many search results pertaining to `FFmpeg` but I not helpful towards `avconv`

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output_volume=volume=6dB:precision=
fixed'
```

The general sytanx from the man page is:

```
avconv [global options] [[infile options][‘-i’ infile]]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

I having trouble interpreting the documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for i in *.wav; do
    avconv -i "$i" -af volume=6dB:precision=fixed "$i{%.*}".mp3
done
```